# Tizen ide quits when tries to create new project

Tags: eclipse, tizen

```
[000:239] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:239] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:240] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:240] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
```

i am frozen with there errors in terminal while i tries to create new project. the eclipse ide closes without any errors.please help

Answer (score 0):

### I face this problem in ubuntu 12.04. Just uninstall google-talkplugin , after that open the Tizen ide , this time you can create project.

Happy Tizen development